# How do I get the latest or even realtime information of institutions stock buy/sell action?

Tags: stocks

Is there any place/website that I can check out big institutions stock buy/sell data?

For example, I want to trace all the transactions made by JP Morgan. Is there any way I can check it out?

Thanks,

Comment: What do you mean by "big institutions"?  Publicly held companies?  Privately held companies?  Governments?  Private investors?

Comment: I doubt such a thing exists, at least, not available to the regular consumer. The big institutions themselves may have private systems set up to track these things.

Comment: @JL Thanks, so this kind of information can be considered as somewhat private property?

Answer (score 1):

Of course not, this is confidential information in the same way that I cannot phone up your bank and ask to see a list of the transactions that you have made.

Any bank has to be extremely careful about protecting the private transactions of it's customers and would be subject to heavy fines if it revealed this information without the customer's consent.